# Calling delegated constructor while creating new object with `this`

Tags: c++, qt, constructor, delegates

Let's say I have a class that initializes several member pointers by passing itself to them (reduced to only `A`). It is a [common practice in Qt](https://doc.qt.io/qt-6/objecttrees.html) to pass the parent widget.

```
class B : public Base{
public:
    B() :
        my_a(new A(this))
    {  ...  }
    A* my_a;
};
```

But to make it testable I'd like to set those pointers from the outside, preferably passing in the constructor without duplicating everything between the brackets.
That might look like this:

```
class B : public Base{
    public:
    B() :
        B(new A(this))
    {   }
    B(A* a) :
        my_a(a)
    {  ...  }
    
    A* my_a;
};
```

From `B`'s default constructor we call the specialized version of it. But the problem is that it cause an undefined behavior - sometimes crashing but sometimes produce 'impossible' output. I was able to narrow it down till the `: B(new A(this))` part - calling a delegate constructor while creating a new object with `this`.

The question: What cause the UB in that case? Is it possible to use delegate constructors while initializing new object with the current instance?

If nothing works I would create 2 constructors without delegating and an `init` method to remove code duplication.

Ps. consider `Base` as `QWidget`, while `A` and `B` being custom widgets.

Edit:
Here's a [short version](https://godbolt.org/z/GYW3jjYM8) of it that can be compiled but different runs can produce different output:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

class Base 
{
    public:
    int get_int() const {return my_int;};
    
    int my_int = 5;
};

class A
{
public:
    A(Base* base = nullptr)
    {
        if(base != nullptr) {
            my_i = base->get_int();
        } else {
            my_i = 42;
        }
    }
        
    int my_i;
};

class B : public Base{
    public:
    B() :
        B(new A(this))
    {
        
    }
    B(A* a) :
        my_a(a)
    {}
    
    
    A* my_a;
};

int main ()
{
    B b;
    std::cout << b.my_a->my_i;
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: what exactly do you mean when you write "But the problem is that it cause an undefined behavior" ?

Comment: please post a [mcve] and describe the problem you observe (not only your interpretation of it. If you knew it was UB then you'd already know what this issue is)

Comment: This is what I get after adding the missing pieces to your code https://godbolt.org/z/haoox6Kqf and I see no issue with it. Very likely there is an issue in the code you did not show.

Comment: The problem might be in what `A`'s constructor is doing. While `this` is a valid pointer, the `B` instance is not constructed yet. So `A` can save the pointer for later, but cannot access any members of `B`.

Comment: It's like `B::B(A*a)` occurs before `Base::Base`...

Comment: its not "irrational". Its not what you expect but (no offense) thats because your expectations are off. The issue is `my_i = base->get_int();` before the `B` instance pointed to by `base` is constructed.

Comment: @463035818_is_not_an_ai Within the constructor of `B` the `Base` part of it has to be constructed already.

Comment: Well, the question as-is has already been answered. Now to touch your underlying problem "But to make it testable I'd like to set those pointers from the outside" - you know that in Qt you can access every child UI element by name with [findChild](https://doc.qt.io/qt-6/qobject.html#findChild)? E.g. in your case: `auto* sut->findChild<QWidget*>("myCustomWIdget");`. If needed you can also `dynamic_cast` it to your custom widget type.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In `B() : B(new A(this))` the instance of `A` must be created as part of evaluating the arguments for the delegate constructor. That means it occurs before any initialization happens for `this`, including  before the base class constructor being called. In this case `my_i` is not initialized yet when the `A` is constructed. You then have Undefined Behaviour from reading an uninitialied data member while calling `get_int();`.

In `B() : my_a(new A(this))` the instance of `A` is created in member initializer list, which means it is always created after the base class constructors have finished. In this case `my_i` is initialized before the `A` is constructed and `get_int()` works correctly in `A`'s constructor.